# flash garbage collector and handling events

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, garbage-collection

take a look at the following code

```
var a = new View();
a = null;
....
class View {
    private var clip: MovieCLip

    public function View() {
        clip.addEventListener(...)
    }
}
```

will `a` be in memory after `a = null`? Does `addEventListener` adds a strong refernce?

Comment: Best You can do is remove all event listeners . You can use some exsiting libs for remember added listeners or do it in Your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the references to `clip` are within `a`, GC will pick up both objects and cleanly remove them.

I've taken your example and used an ENTER_FRAME listener to create new `View`s in the same way you did:

[image: Graph object not added to the stage]

If, however, clip were added to the stage, then it would continue to exist, and `a` would also not be removed:

[image: Graph for objects added to the stage]

You can use the `useWeakReference` parameter of `addEventListener` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I use FDT for development, it has a very useful profiler :) http://fdt.powerflasher.com/

Answer (score 2):

By default `addEventListener` adds a strong reference. The last parameter of [addEventListener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) is `useWeakReference`. You can use `true` for this parameter to specify a weak reference.

Comment: so that means that a vil not be removed? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As you describe your example, the object where the event listener is attached will not be garbage collected. Even setting null will not help.

TO get this object goto gc() you can use one of the following approaches:

1. useWeakReference

   `clip.addEventListener(EVENT.name,listenerMethod,false,0,true);`
2. unsubscribe listener.

In handler method

```
function handlerMethod(ev:Event):void
{
  clip.removeEventListener(EVENT.name,listenerMethod);
}
```

Comment: This is actually not true - since no reference to clip exists outside of a, both will be picked up by GC.

Comment: Why do you want a clip out of the stage ?

Comment: It might have been added or removed somewhere else - we don't know.  We only know what's in the code.